# Why do these two plot commands give different results?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

Why the following two MWE codes, using pgfplots with and without gnuplot give different results (a phase shift)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [thick,mark=none,domain=0:6,samples=1000]  {cos(deg(2*x+atan(1)))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [thick,mark=none,domain=0:6,samples=1000]  gnuplot {cos(2*x+atan(1))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `atan` gives its result already in degrees. I think you want to do `cos(deg(2*x)+atan(1))`.

Comment: I get the same result in both cases.

Comment: @Jake I get different results; what Qrrbrbirlbel proposes seems the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PGFmath function `atan` (as well as all other trigonometrical functions) uses angles in degree (either as input or as output).

The `deg` function is used to convert an angle in radians in degrees. The correct way to write this function in PGFmath would be

```
cos(deg(2 * x) + atan(1))
```

or

```
cos(2 * deg(x) + atan(1)) = cos(2 * deg x + atan 1) = cos(2 * deg x + 45)
```

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[thick,domain=0:6, samples=1000]
\addplot [ultra thick] gnuplot {cos(    2*x  + atan(1) )};
\addplot [red]                 {cos(deg(2*x  + atan(1)))};
\addplot [green]               {cos(deg(2*x) + atan(1) )};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]